# Getting the following error in my console while trying to import products using CSV

Tags: magento-1.7

> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in **/home/magentosite/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php** on line **390**

I am using Magento core import functionality in Magento 1.7.0.2

How can I solve this?

Comment: You're going to need to provide us with the code you are using. It's apparent you are trying to call ->getName() on a variable that is not an object. In order to figure out why you are getting it, we need to know how you are trying to pull your collection.

Comment: This question needs an [mcve] to be solveable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the product first

```
$mageProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$SKU);
```

Thanks